# how to get more than 5000 entities by using Factories GetByFilter method with prestasharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, prestashop-1.7

Library Version:

1.2.9

NuGet Package Url:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PrestaSharp/1.2.9

Prestashop version:

1.7.7.0

Describe the Bug:

PrestaSharp GetByFilter with pagination always return same entity list

Since ProductFactory's GetByFilter method returns null if there are more than 5000 products that match the filter. I decide to get them by pagination like this

```
_productFactory.GetIdsByFilter(filter, null, "[" + startingIndex.ToString() + "," + count.ToString() + "]");
```

but even if startingIndex(because of a loop) changes the result is the same

Full code:

```
filter.Add("date_upd", "[" + dFrom + "," + dTo + "]");

int i = 0;

List<long> AllProducts = new List<long>();
List<long> products;
while (true) // this loop never breaks
{ 
    int startingIndex = i++  * count;
    products = _productFactory.GetIdsByFilter(filter, null, "[" + startingIndex.ToString() + "," + (count).ToString() + "]"); // returns same products in every iteration
    if (products?.Any() == true) // to check the list is not empty
    {
        AllProducts.AddRange(products);
        if (products.Count < count)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: You are not incrementing `i` thus your starting index is always 0

Comment: I was already increasing the index, I forgot to write. sorry, i edited the post now.

Comment: What is `count`? If its `0`: `i++ * 0  = 0`, `startingIndex` value wont change ever and will be `0`.

Comment: Assuming, that `count` is also different from `0` your code seems correct. What is the value of `count` and how many products are returned by your query?

Comment: count is not zero, i tried different count values such as 100 and 1000, but the result is always same

Comment: if filter mached with any product, the loop never breaks because everytime there are products.

Comment: If that's the case, this seems like an issue in the library or the prestashop instance itself. Have you tried executing the api requests directly in the prestashop api with a tool like postman? It's quite impossible to reproduce this issue without a running instance of prestashop, thus it might be best if you contact the author of the library or the prestashop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the brackets from the 'limit' parameter. It is an error in the Github documentation when they give the example with brackets. Here's an own implementation where I send multiple requests in parallel to speed up the processing, regards.

```
public async Task<List<PS_Entity>> GetElements(int pageSize = 100) {
            try {
                var numberOfElements = factory.GetIds().Count;
                var numberOfParallelTasks = numberOfElements >= pageSize ? numberOfElements / pageSize : 1;
                var loadElementsTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfParallelTasks).Select(taskNumber => factory.GetByFilterAsync(null, "id_ASC", $"{taskNumber * pageSize},{pageSize}")).ToList();
                if (numberOfElements % pageSize != 0) {
                    var skiped = numberOfParallelTasks * pageSize;
                    loadElementsTasks.Add(factory.GetByFilterAsync(null, "id_ASC", $"{skiped},{numberOfElements - skiped}"));
                }
                var elements = (await Task.WhenAll(loadElementsTasks)).SelectMany(elements => elements).ToList();
                return elements;
            } catch (PrestaSharpException e) {
                if ((int)e.ResponseHttpStatusCode == 404)
                    Console.WriteLine($"No existen {RemoveFactoryFromName(factory)}'s.");
                return new List<PS_Entity>();
            }
        }
```